ALB balancing an IIS application with an specific Identity account is not working
I have an IIS ASP.NET MVC application with session state in SQL Server installed on two machines in AWS cloud with an AWS Application Load Balancer in front of them.
If I use NetworkService as the identity in IIS, it's working, but when I use a local account (with admin privileges and in the IIS_IUSRS group), the authentication is not working between servers.
I don't understand which is exactly the error, but the effect on the web is that the authentication cookie is not shared between both servers and the user is not authenticated after set the credentials. The authentication is done in a server (and the auth cookie sent) but the next request is against the other server and the sessionstate is not recovered. But I can't understand in which way the IIS Identity user is involved in the sessionstate (sqlserver) management.
The sessionState configuration is exactly the same. Somehting like that:
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" cookieName="ASP.NET_SessionId_4344" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" sqlConnectionString="...connection string with dbuser and password..." cookieless="false" timeout="20" />


What do you mean by "is not working", unexpected behavior, error messages, no response? Can you edit your question and describe whats happening/what you expected. Add any relevant error messages or logs from Windows Event Logs, IIS Application Logs, IIS HTTPERR log etc. Where is your apps webroot folder? Is your local account a member of IIS_IUSRS?  Can you explain how your session state is setup? Can you explain how your SQL Server is setup? Sounds like you might have 2 sessionstate databases, and the ALB is sending traffic to both in a round-robin?

Thanks, I've added some info about the error. And following your comment, we've added the usr in the IIS_IUSRS group, but the user cannot work with sessionstate in both servers.

Are you sure the session state works properly when your using networkservice? From your description it sounds like you have 2 session state databases - and by default they are separate. Its possible to setup replication, but it would be easier to use RDS to host the session state database centrally, then both IIS can talk to a single database. If sessionstate is indeed working with networkservice (which i dont see why the user would make much difference), you'll need to dig in the logs, or increase verbosity to find an actual error. Still not a lot to go on here.

It sounds incredible but that is the problem, the sessionstate configuration is cloned, it's exactly the same. And when we set NetworkService as IIS Identity it works sharing session between servers and when we change to another specific user, it fails. We've implemented a workaround to access to the shared resource which needs that account, but we'll try again later to understand what is failing.
